# No entiendo las sobrecargas

Tags: java

Realizar las funciones  para `mostrar(String texto)`  `int pedirValores(String texto)` con las sobrecargas correspondientes para validar la entradas en JAVA.

**Sobrecargas**

```
int pedirValores()

int pedirValores(String texto)

int pedirValores(String texto, int Max)

int pedirValores(String texto, int Max, int Min)

int pedirValores(int Min, String texto) * cambio de orden de los parámetros
```

Más adelante realizaremos una clase llamada Utilidades donde a lo largo del curso se añadirn métodos (funciones o procedimientos) que utilizaremos de manera recurrente durante el curso. Será nuestra caja de herramientas/ navaja suiza para hacer las actividades.

nota: En ella tendremos métodos para `mostrar(String texto)`  `int pedirValores(String texto)` y más funcionalidades...

Comment: Buenvenido, es demasiado importante mostrar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Java te permite poder crear métodos que se llamen igual pero que puedan comportarse de forma diferente.

En tu método `pedirValores()` si te fijas no hay ningún argumento entre los paréntesis. Lo que haga por dentro dicho método podría estar fijado por ejemplo a alguno de los atributos de su clase.

En cambio `pedirValores(String texto)` difiere notablemente en que ahora sí pide una variable para poder funcionar, en este caso un `String` con el nombre `texto`.

Método sin argumentos (te devolverá por ejemplo la longitud de un String de tu clase):

```
public int pedirValores() {
    return this.abritubo.length();
}
```

Método con argumentos (te devolverá por ejemplo la longitud del String que hayas incluido como argumento):

```
public int pedirValores(String texto) {
    return texto.length();
}
```

Cuando estés trabajando con tu clase, podrás llamar a cualquier de las dos según tus necesidades:

```
MiClase clase = new Clase("hola");
String texto = "hasta luego";

clase.pedirValores();        // Te devolverá 4
clase.pedirValores(texto);   // Te devolverá 11
```

En resumidas cuentas:

El poder sobrecargar un método te permitirá tener una misma función para diferentes usos.

Comment: Gracias david :)